# How to add RNCryptor in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, addition, rncryptor

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa
import RNCryptor.h // this line give me problem
```

I am new to Swift and I want to work with encryption. When I add RNCryptor I get an error saying "module not found".

Comment: How are you adding RNCryptor to your project?

Comment: Please read the [RNCryptor description](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor). There is an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're performing a manual install (rather than Carthage or Cocoapods). Your `import RNCryptor.h` is in the wrong place. Here are the relevant [docs](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor):

- If you already have a bridging header file, add `#import "RNCryptor.h"` (or the path to which you copied RNCryptor.h).
- If you don't have a bridging header:

  - Swift project: In your target's Build Settings, set "Objective-C Bridging Header" to your path for RNCryptor.h. (Or create a bridiging header and follow instructions above.)
  - ObjC project: Xcode will ask if you want to create a bridging header. Allow it to, and add #import "RNCryptor.h" to the header (or the path to which you copied RNCryptor.h)

The `import "RNCryptor.h"` goes in your bridging header, not your Swift code.

If you're new to Swift, however, I would encourage you to look into CocoaPods to bring in your dependencies. When I wrote those docs encouraging you to install RNCryptor by hand (I'm the "RN" in RNCryptor), I was not a fan of CocoaPods, but I've grown to believe it's an important part of Cocoa development and worth learning. I now use it on all my new projects.